# Compare two databases and see which one is not in the other

Tags: swift, realm

Now I have one database with a new names. It is set up as Objects like this:

```
class Users: Object {

    @objc dynamic var userID = ""
    @objc dynamic var username = ""
    @objc dynamic var inputDate = Date()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userID"
    }
}
```

I have a refresh button, and when that button is pressed, it will retrieve a new list of names. When the new list is retrieved, some of the names may be deleted. How can I detect which `userID`'s has been removed? Or should I save the new list as new objects, example `class Users2: Object {` and compare those two objects/databases? - any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a high level solution involving Swift 4 Set's

Assuming we start with two arrays of people, one with the existing data and the second with new data where some of the people in the first array were removed.

```
let array1 = ["Kirk", "Spock", "Bones", "Scotty"]
let array2 = ["Kirk",          "Bones", "Scotty"]
```

convert the arrays to sets

```
let s1 = Set(array1)
let s2 = Set(array2)
```

then to find which people where removed we use the Set operation .subtracting on the sets.

```
let removedPeopleSet = s1.subtracting(s2)
print(removedPeopleSet)
```

and the result

```
["Spock"]
```

One gotcha here is that sets are unordered, so you'll need to sort when converting to an array, if needed.

This technique can be used directly on your objects because they are ObjC objects and conform to hashable/equatable which is required when working with Sets.

Comment: Am I able to see if a new `userID` has been added also?

Comment: @CannonCen Yes, you can use any property of an object to make the comparison. Check out the Object Comparison section of [Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35) and in particular note that *You can override isEqual: in a subclass to have Swift and Objective-C APIs determine equality based on the contents of objects rather than their identities.*

Comment: I see. I am using this for a `Followers for Instagram` look-a-like application. Will it be a good idea to do it this way, to get the users unfollowed me & new followers?

Comment: @CannonCen It's purely a design choice based on the flow of the application. Can it work that way? Sure! Is it the 'best' way? Possibly. If you  have 20k followers and then want to determine which users from a new dataset were removed, loading all of that into Set's would probably not be the best solution. You will probably want to implement some tracking information (via events) into the database itself. Like when a user unfollows; it would be better that when a user unfollows, you get a notification of that change and they are removed from your follower list immediately.

Comment: _ it would be better that when a user unfollows, you get a notification of that change and they are removed from your follower list immediately._ How exactly would I do that?

Comment: @CannonCen [Realm Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) of course! The docs are pretty clear an include an example.

Comment: But notifications wont work, because the actions are not taken from the app?

Comment: @CannonCen What actions would occur that are not driven by the app. i.e. to follow someone you would need to do it within the app, therefore a notification could occur.

Comment: Oh, I ment my app. I didn't know that notification detect a action from the Instagram app

Comment: It won't detect anything from the actual Instagram app as that's not *your* app. It will however, work with the app you create - the one that you are creating that is an instagram look-a-like application per your above comment. If my answer helped you, be sure to accept it so it can help others!

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood me. I am creating a Followers for Instagram look-a-like application, to track followers, unfollowers etc..

Comment: @CannonCen It's your app and you control the data so when a follower is added or removed, your app will be notified of that event and can process the event accordingly.